# Sencha: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I encountered an error `Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` on my console.

This error is from Ext.toolbar.Toolbar class located on `node_modules/Toolbar.js` of my universal app. I use open tooling to generate my app.
[image]

Upon checking the Toolbar.js, the Ext.toolbar.Separator is in the uses property. Supposed to be the ext classes shouldn't be modified and I don't know why this error suddenly occurred.
I build the app using sencha app build dev/testing mode and it succeeds but it has the console error above. When building on production, it fails also and outputs the same error above.

From sencha app build --prod output:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a valid argument for '''instanceof''' (evaluating '''component instanceof Ext.toolbar.Separator''')
```

Can somebody explain why this error occurs? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share more code, where do you define component?

Comment: Just to get past the issue, have you tried simply requiring `Ext.toolbar.Separator`?

Comment: My suspect is `Ext.toolbar.Separator` is not defined in your case.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the help. I was able to fix this error. Somehow the cause is from a different file/class which I really find weird. it threw this error but it is not the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
if (component.xtype === 'tbseparator') {
   ...
```